# Makemigrations Django, não reconhece campos do model

Tags: python, django

Sempre que executo `manage.py makemigrations` em meu projeto, são criados somente os campos "ID" das tabelas.
Tentei exclui os arquivos da pasta `/migrations` pra corrigir o problema, mas sem sucesso.

Model:

```py
class Pais(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True,
  auto_created=True, verbose_name='ID'),
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name='NAME'),
  name_pt = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name='NAME_PT'),
  sigla = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=False, verbose_name='SIGLA'),
  bacen = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name='BACEN'),

  class Meta:
    db_table = 'pais'

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Arquivo de *migration* inicial:

```py
migrations.CreateModel(
  name='Pais',
  fields=[('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True,primary_key=True,serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
    ],
  ),
# ...
```

Comment: cara, se o código tiver exatamente assim, provavelmente o problema é a indentação.

Comment: sua variáveis deveriam estar dentro do escopo da classe. Além disso o nome do método está com erro de digitação, você escreveu `__unit__`  com a letra `"u"`. Mas isso não está relacionado com o problema.

Comment: no colar ficou todo formatado errado, mas esta dentro da classe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oque acontecia e que ao final de cada atributo eu havia colocado " , "
Removi as virgulas e exclui todos os arquivos iniciais de migrate e funcionou certinho.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).